# Snakemake conda env path and Homer annotatePeaks.pl

Tags: conda, snakemake

I would like to use HOMER annotatePeaks.pl (http://homer.ucsd.edu/homer/ngs/annotation.html) from my own defined yaml env.
I need to get this Perl script:

```
perl /home/rj/miniconda3/envs/metylace/share/homer/.//configureHomer.pl -install hg19
```

where my miniconda3 path will be conda env path.
Is it possible?
Is there way to match current rule and conda env hash?

Long story:
There is a wrapper for that but I am curious about other way.
The wrapper uses the option to specify the fasta file, but HOMER has the ability to download the reference itself.
However, prior to that I have call a perl script and download it. But this Perl script is somewhere in the conda env path and conda doesnt use names, but hashes.
How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Snakemake will activate the environment, one should be able to use the `CONDA_PREFIX` environment variable to locate the directory. The other issue is that the `share/homer/` directory appears to be version specific. For example, I see `share/homer-4.11-0`. As long as there is only one - which I think is a fair assumption - you should be able to get away with:

```bash
perl $CONDA_PREFIX/share/homer*/configureHomer.pl -install hg19
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried just know and it seems to work!